# Bundle files with Compose for Desktop (Compose Multiplatform)

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, compose-desktop, compose-multiplatform

I am an Android developer and I have experience with Jetpack Compose. Now, I am trying to build desktop apps, so I found this **Compose for Desktop** project. I want to store a `JSON` file with my desktop app so that I can read the file from my desktop app and show it to users.
Not only JSON files, but I also want to store some other files like HTML.

In Android, I could use the `raw` or `assets` folders, but I don't know how to do that in Compose for Desktop.

If someone can point me in the right direction, I will appreciate it.

Comment: Maybe proto dataStore ?

Comment: @Crebain yes, but I have other files as well so I really need a way to store files within the application. (I edited my question)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put any assets files inside `src\jvmMain\resources` access them using `useResource`.

for example to read `json` file as text:

```kotlin
useResource("data.json") { stream ->
    val textJson = stream.bufferedReader().use { it.readText() }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way (similar to Android raw or assets directory) would be this as [explained in their docs](https://github.com/JetBrains/compose-multiplatform/tree/master/tutorials/Native_distributions_and_local_execution#packaging-resources).

Create a directory structure like this in your project root directory:

```
 myProject
  └───  myDirectory // Its name does not matter
      ├───  common  // Files shipped for all platforms
      ├───  windows // Files shipped for windows
      ├───  linux   // Files shipped for linux
      └───  macos   // Files shipped for macos
```

Now, if you want your file to be available in all platforms, place it in the `common/` directory. If you want it to by only available in Windows, place it in `windows/` directory. and so on.

Then in your project *build.gradle.kts* specify `myDirectory` like this:

```kotlin
compose.desktop {
    application {
        // ...
        nativeDistributions {
            // ...
            appResourcesRootDir = (rootDir.toPath() / "myDirectory").toFile()
        }
    }
}
```